# Given the type string::size_type, is string also a namespace in C++?

Tags: c++

When I typed this in my program,

```
using namespace string;
```

it raised the error that 'string' is not a namespace-name.
So why does it use :: operator rather than .(dot) operator?
Thanks very much!

Comment: What do you mean? Where "does it use" the scoping operator `::`? Please elaborate in the question body (and keep the title a short one-sentence summary). Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you are referring to the std::string, then it is not a namespace but an alias to std::basic_string, there is no namespace as "string" in standard. Can you please provide more context to your question? It's rather confusing.

Comment: The `::` is called the "scope resolution operator" for a reason.   It is used to obtain names in different named scopes.   A namespace is one type of named scope - and a `using`-directive (aka `using namespace`) can be applied to namespaces.   A class is associated with another type of named scope, but is not a namespace, so cannot be the the subject of a `using`-directive.  `std::string` is an alias for a class (actually an instantiation of a templated class, but still a class), so `using namespace string` (or `using namespace std::string`) is invalid.

Comment: @Peter: Please do not put answers in the comment fields. That makes it impossible to accept it (and it is the better answer, IMO)

Comment: @Dylan Liu: You can actually write `using size_type = std::string::size_type;` and that works always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is the name of a class. `std` is the name of a namespace. They’re two different things, but in this context they do the same thing: they name a **scope** that can, in turn, contain other names. `::` is the **scope resolution operator**. It says to look up the name that follows it in the scope whose name precedes it. So `A::B` is the `B` that comes from the scope named `A`. `::` with no name in front of it refers to the global scope.

```
namespace A { typedef int x; }
class C { typedef double x; }
typedef std::string x;

x;    // std::string
::x;  // std::string
C::x; // double
A::x; // int
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because it can contain type definitions (or aliases), does not make it a `namespace` (keyword). `::` was probably chosen because it is *similar enough* that using the same operator is warranted. Note that `.` is only used for *objects* in C++

You can talk about the members of a class being in that class's name-space (not keyword), as both classes and namespaces give you a scope in which to re-use names.